# Find whether a binary mask is straight or not

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, mask

I have binary mask of a long wooden stick with me. I have to find whether the stick is straight or bent from the binary mask. Also find a curvature value if its bent.[This link directs to the mask of a straight line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loa8Y.jpg) [This link directs to the binary mask which is bent, so here i need a curvature or some value which can quantify the degree of bent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOkAD.jpg)

i have tried to find the centre points of the mask and draw a straight line through it inorder to find the bent, but the line was not coming properly and also i was not able to find any other ways to find whether its bent or not.

Comment: fit a linear curve and classify it as a "straight line" if the r squared is greater than some threshold?

Comment: Subtract the filled contour from the filled convex hull. If the difference is near zero, then straight. If it is large it is curved.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to use [cv2.minAreaRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to do this (see section 7b in linked document) since it returns the height and width of the minimally-sized, rotated containing rectangle.

Presumably you have an idea of the expected ratio of the width to the length of the stick, so as the stick becomes more curved its length will decrease and its width will increase.

Another possibility is to calculate the percentage of white vs black pixels in the enclosing rectangle... straight sticks will have no/fewer black pixels. On this idea, you should be able to count the white pixels in your mask with one of the `countNonZero()` functions, then fill in or draw the rotated rectangle also in white and then count the white pixels again - the difference is the number of black pixels in the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to measure the curvature is to:

1. Compute the skeleton (medial axis), use a method that produces as few side branches as possible. If necessary, trim excessive side branches in a separate step.
2. Fit a parametric curve through the remaining points, and determine the curvature of the curve.

If the curvature of the stick is constant along its length, it would be natural to fit a circle. The simplest way to robustly fit a circle to many points is to follow the RANSAC method: pick three random points, find the circle that fits them, see how many of your points match the found circle, and rinse and repeat until the fit is good enough.

The curvature is one over the radius of the fitted circle.